# Add/Delete Data from Database in JTable improperly

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, awt

I create Jtable that store data from the database that I can delete/add  contents' the Jtable with Jbutton. When I t try to run the code, I got this result:

1. When I add data into Jtable twice,there is data in it with an extra blank row
2. When I delete data into Jtable twice,data in a specific row is deleted but it add a transparent blank row too.

Why does this happen?

Here the code that I think there is a problem:

```
//add,delete button
final JToggleButton tglbtnAdd = new JToggleButton("Add");
final JToggleButton tglbtnDelete = new JToggleButton("Delete");


JButton button = new JButton("1");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent arg0) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection dbconbt1 = DriverManager.getConnection("" +"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=Store;user=sa;password=");
            Statement sqlstatement = dbconbt1.createStatement();
            ResultSet dbresultset1 = sqlstatement.executeQuery("select * from Store.dbo.Product where ProductID = 'P-1'");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmetadata = dbresultset1.getMetaData();       // Get metadata on them
            int numcols = rsmetadata.getColumnCount();    // How many columns?
            //  Get column names

            for (int i = 1; i <= numcols; i++) {
                defaultmodel2.addColumn( rsmetadata.getColumnName(i));
            }

            if(tglbtnAdd.isSelected() == true) {
                while (dbresultset1.next()) {   
                    Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(numcols);
                    for (int i = 1; i <= numcols; i++) {
                        row.addElement( dbresultset1.getObject(i) );
                    }
                    defaultmodel2.addRow(row );
                }
            }

            if(tglbtnDelete.isSelected() == true) { 
                /**while (dbresultset1.next())
                {    
                    Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(numcols);
                    row.removeElement( dbresultset1.getObject(0) );
                } 
                 */ 
                defaultmodel2.removeRow(0);
            }
            //  Get row
            dbresultset1.close();
            sqlstatement.close();
            dbconbt1.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your table structure on form load only, and just take your data from `JTextField`'s (or from whatever you use) into `Object` array. Finally, add the object array to your model. For delete, just call `model.removeRow()` method.

Comment: Can you give me more information? I don't get it and the data that put into jtable is come from the database.